# plugin shortcodes not working on custom theme- unsure how to fix

Tags: plugins, shortcode

[Live site.](http://www.massagebybodyworx.com)

I've got a custom theme that is giving me slight issues with shortcodes- they don't work. When I switched back to the default theme, the shortcodes worked fine. What do I need to look for in my custom theme to be the culprit?

If it matters, the shortcodes are for Contact Form 7 and Bookings plugins.

contact.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<h2>Tell us, what's on your mind? Questions, comments, hellos- share them below.</h2>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?> 



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: off my head is to make sure your theme has 'wp_head();` in header.php and `wp_footer();` in footer.php

Comment: `wp_head` is just above the closing `</head>` in header.php and `wp_footer` is just after the opening `<div id="footer">` in footer.php

Comment: Set `WP_Debug` to `TRUE` in `wp-config` and see if you get any errors. Then add those to your question.

Comment: debug shows no errors

Comment: bainternet's suggestion is sound, i had that happen to me once... was working on somebody's old theme that didn't have wp_footer() and was going nuts. what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @helgatheviking i checked header.php and footer.php, both seemed to be configured properly- contained `wp_head` and `wp_footer`, respectively. as far as what exactly isn't working- i've put the shortcode for Contact Form 7, for example, in the contact page and everything(ie- header, footer, `<p>` content, etc) shows up.. except for the contact form

Comment: is it particular page template?  does it have the_content()?  doesn't appear to be displaying any text.. can you show text other than the shortcode?  do you have any improperly closed html in the html view?

Comment: @helgatheviking  thank you for your continued help. i've added the content of contact.php to my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the loop itself. As others suspected, you don't have `the_content()` to display the page content.

Change your loop to this and that should fix your problem:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ah, i knew it had to be something simple i was overlooking. thank you.

Comment: yup, need the_content()!!  glad you found the solution.